# How to add multiple conditions in JSON schema?

Tags: node.js, json, jsonschema

I have the below JSON schema

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "op": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1,
        "enum": [
          "add",
          "remove",
          "replace"
        ]
      },
      "path": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1,
        "enum": [
          "/name",
          "/description",
          "/prefix"
        ]
      },
      "value": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": [
      "op",
      "path",
      "value"
    ],
    "minItems": 1,
    "allOf": [
      {
        "if" : {
          "properties": {
            "path" : {
              "const": "/name"
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "op": {
              "const": "replace"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "if" : {
          "properties": {
            "path" : {
              "const": "/description"
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "op": {
              "const": "replace"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As above we can see , if name and description are there ,then op will be replace and for path prefix I have all the operations i.e  add , remove and replace , but i want a special condition to be applied for remove operation
Like if path is xFix and op is remove then required parameters should not contain value attrribute , so only op and path.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of JSON data that should pass validation and some examples of JSON data that would fail validation please? And explain which are not validating as you expect (and why)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to turn the logic of that around.  Do not include "value" in the "required" list.  Instead, add a condition that says, basically, "if op is not 'remove', then value is required".

```
  {
    "if" : {
      "not": {
        "properties": {
          "op" : {
            "const": "remove"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "required": ["value"]
    }
  }
```

Comment: with this logic it will be like, if my operation other is than remove, it will just require value, but  for other operations (other than remove) I want all the fields required, but only for remove I want op and path not value

Comment: No, I don't believe that's true.  The properties required by the top-level "required" are always required.  The conditional "required" just adds to them.  That's why you need to reverse the logic from how you had originally stated it, to get this to work - you can't "subtract" requirements with a conditional.  Anyway, it's easy enough to test if you don't trust it.